# Issues when sculpting with python api on imported object

Tags: python, sculpting, stl

I have run into a problem concerning the application of sculupt brush strokes via the python api. I have a script that applies a brush stroke at either a given vertex group or to a set of vertices in a given radius around chosen vertex.
This works fine with random meshes.
My issue arose when i tried to apply the same method to an object i imported from an stl file.
The issue is that no the stroke is always applied in the same location regardles of what vertices i chose for the brush stroke.
I checked my code multiple times and tried it with different objects, not encountering the same issue.
Sculpting manually also works just fine.
My guess is that some property of the object is not correct due to it beeing importet from a stl file. Some help would be great beacuse i need to get this to work for my bachelors thesis.

Comment: Maybe clear any custom Split Normals from the imported object in case that is affecting your code? Should be under Geometry on the R/H Object Data Properties panel (green triangle).

Comment: Well it seems the issue is caused by scaling the object down from its importet size. It somehow messes with my coordinates even though it shouldnt

Comment: Did you apply the scale (Ctrl-A) after you'd scaled your object down?

Comment: Thanks a lot, that solved my issue.

Comment: Good news! Glad it helped.